# HP Photosmart C4180 & Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: drivers, printing, hp

I have an HP Photosmart C4180 printer attached to my Ubuntu 17.10 machine via USB and I can't get it to print correctly.  Every print job prints out 1 or 2 pages of some, or a lot of garbled characters and then freezes.  If I go to Settings->Devices->Printers I see the print job is halted with the option to resume. Selecting "resume" then prints the job correctly from the beginning.

I have HP's HPLIP installed. The closest driver seems to be the series C4100, which is selected. The Xsane scanner works perfectly. But printing documents doesn't.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled this printer several times with the same results. Curiously, the printer test page from CUPS (localhost:631) works perfectly when using a CUPS based printer setup, but only from the localhost console. Otherwise, the CUPS printer prints the same as the HPLIP.

Basically, I don't know what I'm doing. I recently ditched Windows where there seems to be a lot more device support and I had a lot more familiarity. It just seemed easier to find solutions, but returning to Windows is just not an option.

Answer (score 0):

so this device needs hplip 1.6 and no plug-in needed; so 17.10 ubuntu should be fine;

to use hplip, if you open a terminal (hold down three keys: control and alt and t all at once ..); then type `hp-setup` and hplip should find the device and set it up; hopefully that process will offer you a test print; another icon is likely to appear in your PRINTERS folder; see what it calls the printer driver for that;

if this does not work, type `hp-check` for hplip to check if all the support programmes that it needs to run; are installed; you can copy what it gives you and edit the above answer; to include the results; if IT GIVES YOU AN ERROR

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. 

I've run hp-setup a number of times.  I have the ability to select the right printer but the driver it installs is for the entire 4000 series. 

I don't see any real errors following hp-check other than a warning concerning plug-ins not being installed:

Current contents of '/var/lib/hp/hplip.state' file:
Plugins are not installed. Could not access file: No such file or directory.

I'm beginning to suspect the problem is with HP. I can't find anyone else who has tried to install the C4180.